# Issue serializing checkbox as boolean property and MVC binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application i have a model with boolean property

```
public class MyModel
{
  [DisplayName("Inherit")]
  public bool IsInherit{get;set;}
}
```

**razor view**

```
<form id="myform">
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsInherit)
</form>
```

This will render html page as ( assuming `IsInherit` is true)

```
<form id="myform">
   <input name="IsInherit" id="IsInherit" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The Inherit field is required." data-val="true">
   <input name="IsInherit" type="hidden" value="false">                    
</form>
```

When check box is selected and if i serialize the form using jQuery `$("#myform").serialize()` then the resultant string is

`IsInherit=true&IsInherit=false`

and upon AJAX POST, MVC's databinding correctly sets the model property value to `true` as expected.

However, in certain cases, i need to serialize the form as object. And for that i have below custom jquery extension method that serializes the form as object

```
(function() {
    $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
                    if (o[this.name]) {
                        if (!o[this.name].push) {
                            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                        }
                        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                    } else {
                        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                    }
                });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery)
```

When i serialize the form using this extension method `$("#myform").serializeObject()` the resultant object has `IsInherit` property of type array with two values `true` and `false`

and when i AJAX POST the json object to server, the MVC biding does not work. and i get error `The Inherit field is required.`

How do i fix this issue?

Note that the issue is when check box is checked because when check box is checked `serializeObject` method creates property of type array and i guess MVC binding does not know how to bind it.
If check box is not checked then everything works fine

Comment: If you replace `if (!o[this.name].push) {` with `if (o[this.name] && o[this.name] != "true") {` it will solve the issue with your checkbox, but will be a problem if your model actually has an collection property containing a value "true" (albeit unlikely you have that). Why do you think you need to use your `serializeObject()` function? If you have generated you view correctly then that should not be necessary

Comment: The view has Kendo ListView along with other fields. Most of the kendo controls have data source underneath.   So i can attach data directly to jason object like  `var obj = $("#myform").serializeObject(); obj["ListViewData"] = listView.dataSource.data();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified my javascript and use the bitwise operator `|` to set the value if it's boolean

```
(function () {
    $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if ((typeof (this.value) === "boolean") ||
                    (typeof (this.value) === "string" && this.value != undefined && (this.value.toLowerCase() === "true" || this.value.toLowerCase() === "false"))) {
                    o[this.name] = ((o[this.name] == "true") | (this.value == "true")) ? true : false; //Sets value to true if one of two bits is true
                }
                else {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                }
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery)
```